# Make a jar that has a classifier by default

Tags: maven

We have a project called `core-services`. This builds three jars:

- `core-services-client` Contains all client classes
- `core-services-server`: Contains all server and client classes
- `core-services-test`: Contains all junit classes

Right now, I build the `core-services-server` jar by default, and then use assemblies to build the `client` and `test` jars. If a developer wants to use the client or test jars, they must specify a classifier. However, when they want to depend upon the server jar, they don't specify a classifier.

This will lead to developers just using the server jar when they really should be using the client jar. I'd like to build all three jars to require a classifier when using them as a dependency. However, I can't do this when specifying the project:

```
<groupId>com.vegicorp</groupId>
<artifactId>core-services</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<classifier>server</classifier>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

I know I can use `<finalName>` to call the default jar `core-services-server`, but I want to make sure that if a developer depends upon the `core-services`, they must say whether they want the server, the client, or the testing classes. If I merely rename it, they will get the server jar by default.

How can I specify that the default jar has a classifier of `server`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I can put the default classifier into the `maven-jar-plugin` configuration in my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- All other configuration information is in the parent pom -->
    <configuration>
        <classifier>server</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I do `mvn deploy`, I get a *warning* that `No primary artifact to deploy, deploying attached artifacts instead`, and all three jars deploy with classifiers.

Comment: You'll get an error with the latest version (3.0.2) of the JAR Plugin. Your project should be of `pom` packaging when all it has are attached artifacts.